# Inserting into a strings with special characters into an json mysql column (using php/mysql/Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-json

I am performing an insert on db table that has a column called `json_props` - when a word that has special characters like `Everyone's` this appears in the json column (and back on the frontend) like this

`{"col1": "Everyone&#39;s"}`

I am using the Laravel framework what is the best/recommended Laravel way to insert/escape this correctly into the database.

-- Expected output --

Insert string with special character (like an apostrophe) and it should look normal on the frontend like this e.g
`term's`

-- Actual Output --

`term&#39;s`

Comment: are you using json data in blade?

Comment: no blade template - it is rendered in plain HTML

Answer (score 0):

> when a word that has special characters like `Everyone's` this appears in the json column (and back on the frontend) like this `{"col1": "Everyone&#39;s"}`

This is the client software which replaces a quote char with according entity during inserting the value into the table. Not MySQL.

Find the place in your code where this substitution is performed, and replace it with quote char doubling. Then the value will be successfully saved and retrieved with MySQL.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (json_props JSON);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"col1": "Everyone''s"}');
> SELECT CAST(json_props AS CHAR) FROM test;
> ```
>
> | CAST(json_props AS CHAR) |
> | --- |
> | {"col1": "Everyone's"} |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d74116894e0bcd2d5abdfa4548a6906)*